# How to generate student report cards in python

Tags: python

I'd like to generate students report cards for the following students in this list

```
JAMES BOND GIRLS' SCHOOL. TERM III 2020 EXAMS                                           
STREAM  ADM POS NAME    KCPE    ENG KIS MAT BIO MKS PTS GRD
EAGLE   51  1   MARY    291 44  36  66  26  172 53  B-
EAGLE   50  1   CARO    304 23  20  60  27  130 53  B-
HAWK    49  3   RUTH    361 34  32  44  43  153 51  C+
EAGLE   48  4   PEREZE  317 33  23  32  55  143 48  C+
EAGLE   47  5   JANE    334 33  12  21  33  99  45  C
HAWK    46  6   JULIA   303 23  23  12  21  79  42  C
HAWK    56  7   CLARICE 353 22  11  11  23  67  41  C
HAWK    57  9   ESTHER  283 23  12  9   12  56  40  C
EAGLE   53  10  MELVIN  284 43  21  32  22  118 39  C
HAWK    52  10  MONICAH 286 32  33  23  21  109 39  C
```

A sample for the first student is here below

[image: Sample student report]

The best I could do is this here

```
name = 'MARY '

print('                        JAMES BOND GIRLS SCHOOL')
print('                         EXAMINATION RESULTS')
print('     NAME:',name )
print()
print()
print()
print()
```

Comment: You cant use a gui for this?

Comment: What can be used?

Comment: If you're looking for GUI maybe try tkinter. If you're looking for report like pdf, use ReportLab, pydf2, pdfdocument or FPDF.

The FPDF library is fairly stragihtforward.

Comment: I would say pylatex, but writing all those crazy tables in pylatex might be hard. A simple hacky solution would be to make a sample xls file with all the formatting and then fill it with python script and convert to pdf with pandoc. The key here is to make sure the formatting remains conserved in excel. Haven't done it myself, so can't say for sure. But this would be the easiest for sure.

Comment: Some of those kids need to pick up a textbook and study!  :)

Comment: Haha, @Jeff H that is not real result....

Comment: are you trying to "hit the squares" on an actual form or is the format flexible?  If you have a "pretty form" in Word or something, you might be able to save your data from Python into a data file and do a mail-merge into a nice form

Comment: @Jeff H there was that mail merge that I used but was made by somebody I dont know. It used to pick values from an excel. It's where that image you see in the question is from...But I've since made a python program for the analysis and this report thing is driving me mad

Comment: this might be helpful if you already have the data wrangled in Python: https://pbpython.com/python-word-template.html

Answer (score 2):

In order print Tabular Data in Terminal use tabulate module.

```
from tabulate import tabulate

# Create a header of the table data
table_heading = ["Heading 1", "Heading 2", "Heading 3"]

# a list of list containing inner list as rows of table
table_data = [["value x1", "value x2", "value x3"], ["value y1", "value y2", "value y3"], ["value z1", "value z2", "value z3"]]

# print data in tabular format in terminal
print(tabulate(table_data, headers=table_heading, tablefmt="fancy_grid"))
```

Output:

```
╒═════════════╤═════════════╤═════════════╕
│ Heading 1   │ Heading 2   │ Heading 3   │
╞═════════════╪═════════════╪═════════════╡
│ value x1    │ value x2    │ value x3    │
├─────────────┼─────────────┼─────────────┤
│ value y1    │ value y2    │ value y3    │
├─────────────┼─────────────┼─────────────┤
│ value z1    │ value z2    │ value z3    │
╘═════════════╧═════════════╧═════════════╛
```

There are different table format available. Choose according to your need. It can be used as a grid to suit your layout.

Reference of Module: https://pypi.org/project/tabulate/

Answer (score 1):

Use `reportlab` for generating tables on PDFs in Python. The endgame I think would be that only given, I worked on a system that did this.

Answer (score 0):

You should draft a fillable PDF form then use a package like pdfforms in order to use python to fill out the form.

Comment: Sounds difficult... Wah!!